# How to verify the author of each commit in git

Tags: git, signing, git-commit, git-tag

I'm studying a migration from subversion to git. For starters, a central-repository scheme will be used, just like svn.

The problem is that I want to make sure each commit was created by the real person.

In subversion, assuming you **don't** cache your svn password, you can be sure the commit author is the real author.

From what I read after countless searches on the net, I should create a **signed tag every time I push** the central repository. In order to sign the tag, I should review **each** of the previous commits, to make sure no one changed anything while I was away from the computer (for example introducing malicious code and removing it later, making it invisible in the overall diff, but still being executed in the continuous build/test server).

This means I have to double-check commits: first when I create each commit, and then again when I decide to push with a signed tag. But that is time consuming and redundant. If signed tags are the way to go, then I suppose I should be creating **a signed tag for each commit**. Which will fill the entire repository with tags. That doesn't sound quite right in my opinion.

The cleanest solution I can think of, is **signing each commit** (supported since [git 1.7.9](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt;hb=HEAD)). But for some reason I don't understand, doing that is [totally stupid](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/GPG-signing-for-git-commit-tp2582986p2583316.html). Supported by git, but still supposedly stupid.

What am I supposed to do? Waste time double-checking all commits and doing per-push tag-signing; or tag-signing every single commit; or sign every single commit? Is there an alternative I don't know about?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are really overboard with this whole idea, but if you **really** insist, here is a solution.

Install [Gerrit Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) as your central git server. Configure it to prohibit direct push from people who you do not trust (could be your whole team, and may include yourself).

Now, everybody will be forced to submit to code review first. Have only trusted people to approve changes (again, this could be only you). These approvals will be logged by Gerrit server, and only Gerrit can move branches forward.

From this point on, the only git repository you trust is your Gerrit server, or any other git repo that has exact same sha for all branches you care about.

Q.E.D.

Comment: The whole team is trusted as of now. But if the commits "author" field isn't a reliable information, then commits have to be manually checked (again) before being put in the central repository, to try to detect malicious people having created commits in the name of the trusted workers.

Does not seem very different (in amount of work) from double-checking before creating a signed tag everytime a worker pushes to the central repo.

Comment: If team is trusted, why do you care? Any weird commit should be quickly noticed then. Also, trust issues aside, when everything goes through code review, it increases code quality by like 10x. Even if I am team member with highest privileges possible (direct push, force push, etc), I would NOT want to work without code review now. In fact, I would DEMAND it. It gives you completely different satisfaction from your work - just try it.

Comment: Suppose I have created about 20 commits in my computer this during the last 4 hours. Before I'm able to push them, I'm asked some questions by a coworker, so I leave the desktop unlocked for a minute. But in the end I've spent 30 minutes with my computer out of sight. Meanwhile, someone has interactively rebased the first commit, introducing malicious code, and the last commit, removing the malicious code. All commits still point to me as the author. Then I go back to my computer, and decide to push. I review the general diff, and no malicious code is there. I think everything is in order...

Comment: ...and push (or even add a signed tag, and then push) to the central repo. The continous build/testing system begins testing each of the commits. It arrives at the second commit, with the malicious code that compromises the testing system, introducing a backdoor; then continues testing all commits until the last one. All of them pass correctly. Manual testing does not check every single commit, so it also goes unnoticed by the people doing manual checks. This couldn't have happened in svn like that, since each commit requires a password that only actually trusted workers know.

Comment: You completely missed the whole point about Gerrit-style code review. When you pushed your commits into Gerrit, they did NOT become official just yet - somebody has to approve them, you can configure it to have at least 2 people vote up. After approval, Gerrit moves branch forward, and only then your build/test system engages. But you can also do automatic incremental quick-test builds per every non-approved Gerrit commit - if they fail, Gerrit automatically votes this commit down. In real world, it is very difficult for bad stuff to go unnoticed through this system.

Comment: I was addressing the trust issues you brought to the discussion, not the code review system which, as I said, while being a solution, would still require twice the work that svn requires for the same effect in regards to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust password authentication with with Subversion, you can trust password authentication with git also.

The articles you have been reading on the net probably apply to the open source case, when using signed tags establishes a chain of trust between the commits even if you don't trust the servers hosting the repositories. For Subversion, there is no possibility of not trusting the svn server, so I'm assuming you have a trusted machine. In that case the same applies as with svn: keep your passwords to the machine safe. Git doesn't ever cache the password by itself, but you can use ssh public keys to effectively allow access to the server without entering the password each time.

EDIT: I was assuming you can also trust your team. It is indeed possible to do your commits under the name of anyone. But if the team cannot be trusted to use their own names, you also have bigger problems such as if you can trust the actual *code* from these people.

Comment: I am assuming that, at some point in the future, a problem **will** arise. I cannot control the future, I cannot control if/when a worker will become untrustable or corrupted, and I cannot detect it before it happens.

So **when** it happens, I want to trace the actual author of the problem, so that the correct measures can be taken instantly, instead of having to (probably incorrectly) guess which of all the workers cannot be trusted.

Comment: @STenyaK In that case you don't want a central repository into which anyone can push directly. You need someone you can trust to do that. Yourself, if there is nobody else. Each developer only gets to commit in his/her own home directory, and you pull directly from that repository. Then you know where your commits came from.

Comment: I can currently achieve the goal with central repos using svn, so using a central repository is not a problem. And I believe the 3 alternatives I provide allow to do it in GIT. I'm just asking what is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: @STenyaK: Who maintains the Subversion repository? Because whoever has admin access to that can play merry hell with the security there. You need to have a similar level of trust for whoever has the right to make commits to whichever Git repository/branch you consider to be canonical.

Comment: The repository is not under control of committers, except for making commits that can always be traced back to "whoever knew the password of user X".
I'm not asking if this is the weakest link in security, or if someone with a gun to their head would do malicious commits.
I'm trying to migrate an existing svn behaviour into git. I assume git is technically capable of doing it, so I'm asking how to best do it. This is not a political question, it's a technical question.

Comment: Your developers are going to find out pretty soon that you have no trust in them, if you force them to put a signed tag to each commit to prove they didn't try to fake their identity. I would not expect a very successful migration project in such atmosphere of mistrust. Normally signing is used the other way around. Signing proves a commit really comes from someone you trust, thus you can also trust this commit. Anyway, if you pull yourself from your developers repositories, you can at least appear more subtle with this.

Comment: Once again, this is **not** a political problem. All committers are OK with this, some of them actually raised the question in the first place, mentioning how strange it would be that any one developer leaving an unlocked terminal could lead to commits being created in the name of any of the committers (which can not technically happen with the current svn setup).

Comment: I think you can do what you want with gitolite. See https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK . That file also tries to explain why using it may not be such a good idea after all.

Comment: I took a look at it, but that patch does not check whether the committer is the actual committer (via GPG signing); instead it checks that the person pushing a commit must be the same person who is mentioned as the commit author (not necessarily the actual commit author, since anyone can fake it without signing), which I agree makes no sense.